# How to solve RangeError ERR_INVALID_ADDRESS_FAMILY: Invalid address family

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to do an https GET request with a custom DNS in Node(v12.13.1):

```
https.get('https://example.com',
  {
    lookup(hostname, options, callback) {
      options.family = 4;
      console.log({hostname, options});
      return resolver.resolve4(hostname, options, callback)
    }
  },
  console.log
)
```

But it is throwing an error:

> RangeError [ERR_INVALID_ADDRESS_FAMILY]: Invalid address family:
>   undefined example.com:443

I know that I'm setting the address family correctly because I'm doing it explicitly and logging to confirm. The resolver works by itself:

```
resolver.resolve4('example.com', console.log) prints null ['000.000.000.00' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem can be in format. 
According documentation lookup function must return a result like:

`[{"address":"2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946","family":6}]`